# Intermittent ping timeouts to gateway

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dhcp, packet-loss

Recently I've been experiencing semi-regular connection stutter, especially during active connections (gaming/VoIP). These request timeouts don't appear to have a pattern and can range from slightly annoying to an unusable internet.

I'm on a wired network using a DHCP server. I've tried:

- changing cables
- changing ports (physical)
- flushing DNS, restarting router/modem
- restarting computer + all above
- disabling IPv6

To clarify, every other device on the network is fine, it's just the connection between my computer and the gateway. I'm semi sure it's either a motherboard or driver problem, was hoping to get some insight into which it might be.

Kinda stumped for solutions at this point..

Comment: Is your gateway a standard consumer/home grade device? Its been my experience that your standard linksys or netgear router starts exhibiting issues with volumes of synchronous connections as they start to die (usually when they are about 3 years old). are you sure its not happening to other devices, when your problematic device is engaged in the voiping/gaming? Just one possibility.

Comment: It is pretty standard and moderately old, so that could be the case. I haven't seen any similar behavior while doing ping tests on other devices though.

Comment: ping is never really going to stress a system by itself, so if you see increases in ping time, they are coincidental with whatever else is going on. And it is quite possible you have a cheap or damaged nic on a slow bus or whatever, but replacing a motherboard due to latency spikes seems more like just needing more horsepower. I'd probably buy a 20$ intel nic first, and see if that helps.

Comment: Cheers, might try that :)